# Running Dalekjs Tests on Saucelabs with Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, saucelabs, dalekjs

**what i want:**

run [dalekjs](http://dalekjs.com/)-tests on [saucelabs](https://saucelabs.com/) with [grunt](http://www.gruntjs.com)

**what i did:**

1. installed [grunt-dalek](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-dalek), [dalek-driver-sauce](https://www.npmjs.org/package/dalek-driver-sauce)
2. created grunt config:

   ```
        dalek: {
          options: {
            driver: ['sauce'],
            browser: ['chrome'],
            advanced: {
              "driver.sauce": {
                user: "xxx",
                key: "xxx"
              }
            }
          }
        }
   ```

**what my problem is**

```
Warning: Cannot read property '0' of null Use --force to continue.
```

Comment: Does it work without grunt, using the default dalek cmd client?
If that works, I will check if the configuration reader messes things up when reading from grunt.

(Another idea could be to set up a Dalekfile like in the sauce example & have grunt-dalek use its configuration)

Comment: don't know if you read my answer. treat this comment as a ping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i had some time to dig deeper into this. the error came from **dalek-driver-sauce**.

Function **_verfiyBrowserConfig** inside **browser.js** caused the problem.

```
var browser = browsers[0][browserName] || null;
```

in my config i was missing the **browsers** property.

the dalek-driver-sauce docs are kind of misleading there:

> if you would like to have a more control over the browser/OS combinations that are available, you are able to configure you custom combinations

the browsers config **inside advanced**-config **is mandatory**!

a final working grunt-config looked like this:

```
dalek: {
  options: {
    driver: ['sauce'],
    advanced: {
      "driver.sauce": {
        user: "xxx",
        key: "xxx"
      },
      browsers: [{
        chrome: {
          "platform": "OS X 10.6",
          "actAs": "chrome",
          "version": 27
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  mytest: ['test.js']
}
```